# Random lines on tables bug in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

If you look on this page [here](http://www.pbgametime.com/recruiting/big_board/) in Firefox (I'm on 3.5.2 on a Mac) and scroll up and down, you should see random lines show up in the table.  They are horizontal lines that almost look like underlines that go all the way across the table. Sometimes they are thin and black, sometimes they are thick and blue.  If you don't see them, scroll up and down several times.

Has anyone seen this?  Does anyone know of a fix?

You may also be able to see it [here](http://pbgametime.com/sport/football/2008-2009/).

Comment: i see it in firefox 3.0.13. ive also seen it on some of my tables where table borders sometimes seem to double up. no idea how to fix, sorry

Comment: I think this may be a graphics or browser rendering problem. Your source code for the table looks good. I am using Firefox 3.5.2 on Windows to view, and none of the think black/blue lines are ever displayed while scrolling.

Comment: +1 to spoil an extremely interesting reputation number (666)!

Comment: What a weird rendering glitch. I scrolled the page to get a line to appear, found one I wanted to look at. Opened up Firebug to inspect the element, and the line completely vanished. You could try telling your users to open up Firebug and click the "Inspect Element" button... ;)

Comment: what do you mean **"the table"**? this page is loaded with HTML, I can't guess which table you are referring to. I use FF and I don't see this. I scrolled a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a Mozilla Firefox bug.

Here are two bug reports that are about this error that you've found.

1. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=283229
2. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=426998

Some people reported that it was affected by smooth scrolling. I turned on smooth scrolling and the line stopped appearing (using Firefox 3.5.2), but smooth scrolling bugs me so I'm going to turn it off after I finish posting this.

I never noticed this error before you brought it up, but I never use the scroll bar to scroll pages. This error does not occur with the scroll wheel.

Anyway, looks like there's nothing that can be done for now. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks -- good to know it is an actual bug.  That way I have a good excuse if it comes up.